# Dagger organization for shared dependencies in multiple library projects?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

What's the best way to share dependencies across library projects? I'd like to maintain their independence and just have some thing that explicitly tells the component what it needs, and modules for what it will supply internally.

I can have the libraries all supply a module that the parent Application can add to its component, but if multiple modules provide the same thing, Dagger will (rightly) error out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

Library modules supply an interface of dependencies `DependencyInterface` of what they need. Internally, they'll use their own component that depends on `DependencyInterface`.

Integrating apps will just need to provide their own "implementation" of the interface. If they themselves are using Dagger, then the `AppComponent` will just implement the interface and have Dagger supply the dependencies.

For Example:

The Library component side:

```
@Component(
        modules = {
                // your internal library modules here.
        },
        dependencies = {
                LibraryDependencies.class
        }
)

public interface LibraryComponent {
    // etc...
}

public interface LibraryDependencies {

    // Things that the library needs, etc.
    Retrofit retrofit();

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient();
}
```

For the integrating app side:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = {
                InterfaceModule.class,
                // etc...
        }
)
public abstract class IntegratingAppComponent implements LibraryDependencies {
    // etc...
}


/**
 * This module is just to transform the IntegratingAppComponent into the interfaces that it
 * represents in Dagger, since Dagger only does injection on a direct class by class basis.
 */

@Module
public abstract class InterfaceModule {

    @Provides
    public static LibraryDependencies providesLibraryDependencies(IntegratingAppComponent component) {
        return component;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of this? your solution looks like it could help me.

Comment: @superjugy added a small example.